# How to Use Reflection to Check Method Body Classes and Properties?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to write an app that returns all the error codes of all methods used in the application.

Simply put, given MethodInfo of the below method, how to use Reflection to find out whether Method1 returns a class with Status, Code and Message Properties.
How to find out what values these properties contain?

```
public void Method1()
{
 var response = new Class1()
 {
   Status = Status.Failed,
   Details = new StatusDetails()
   {
     Code = AllCodes.Code1,
     Message = AllMessages.Message1
   }
 }

 return response;
}

MethodInfo mi = typeof(Example).GetMethod("Method1");
MethodBody mb = mi.GetMethodBody();
// how?!
```

Comment: Apart from the method being a `void`, you really don't want to be doing that using reflection. Use unit tests instead.

Comment: Roslyn would be the desired way to go with this kind of code analysis

Comment: @Callum using Roslyn you still can't solve the halting problem (neither with unit tests).

Comment: You didn't read the first very sentence I wrote. I'm trying to write an app that returns all the error codes of all methods used in the application. It's nothing to do with unit tests. I'd need to generate a report.